# Import external Javascript libraries installed via npm in Meteor 1.3

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm, ecmascript-6

I want to use the [OpenSeadragon](http://openseadragon.github.io/#download) library in my Meteor app. As Meteor 1.3 provides support for npm modules, I have installed it via npm using `meteor npm install openseadragon`.

But now I am not sure how to user it. The OpenSeadragon docs only provides an [example](http://openseadragon.github.io/docs/) using the `script tag`.

The meteor [docs](https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html) tell us to use import like `import moment from 'moment';`. But how do I import `openseadragon` as I am pretty sure it doesn't use ES6 modules and doesn't export anything.

How can I use it using the npm import without loading the `openseadragon.js` as global for whole app?

Comment: "pretty user it doesn't use ES6 modules and doesn't export anything" Have you tried? What about standard Node.js style: `var OpenSeadragon = require('openseadragon')`

Comment: @MikeC I searched for `export` in the `openseadragon.js` file but couldn't it. So I assumed it might not be using ES6 modules. I'll try the require method.

Comment: Are you using Blaze, React, or Angular with Meteor?

Comment: @YanickRochon React

Answer (score 2):

The project's (poorly documented) API page states that

> OpenSeadragon will also return an AMD module when required with a loader like Require.js.

Therefore, inside a client script, you can simply

```
import 'openseadragon';  // load globally
```

and it should give you the module constructor

Now, depending on what you are using, you may initialize your container from that constructor. For React container, this would look something like this :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Random } from 'meteor/random';
import 'openseadragon';  // OpenSeadragon on global scope

export default class OpenSeedragonComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      options: {
        id: Random.id(),   // container unique name
        // other options here...
      }
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.initialiseWidgets();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.initialiseWidgets();
  }

  initialiseWidgets() {
    this.viewer = OpenSeadragon(this.state.options);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id={ this.state.options.id } 
           width={ this.props.width || '800px' }
           height={ this.props.height || '600px' }
      >
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

**Note:** at the moment of this writing, you will get an error when loading the `.map` file. Just ignore it, or open an [issue](https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/issues) with the project maintainer so he properly integrate the project with Meteor. Perhaps someone will write a react / meteor package wrapper for it...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But it doesn't work. Getting `Uncaught TypeError: OpenSeadragon is not a function` in console. And `console.log(OpenSeadragon)` still prints an empty object `Object {}`

Comment: It seems that OpenSeadragon is not implementing it's UMD correctly, and a `module.export` is missing. In that case, you'll have to load it globally instead. Let me update the answer...

Answer (score 1):

A JS lib doesn't have to specifically use ES6 export keyword to expose symbols, as a matter of fact npm modules are still using CommonJS `module.exports` in their vast majority because even though package authors write their code in ES6 they publish them to npm using Babel.

In this specific case, you need to globally import the OpenSeadragon lib using `import 'openseadragon';` somewhere in your `client/` folder.

Then it will be available on `window.OpenSeadragon`.

Comment: I didn't mean ES6 specifically. A search for keyword `export` return zero matches in `openseadragon.js` so I believe it doesn't use CommonJS `module.exports` either. 

Also, `console.log(openseadragon)` print an empty object i.e `Object {}` with `import openseadragon from 'openseadragon';`.

Comment: For now, I have placed the `openseadragon.js` file inside `client/lib` folder so it loads automatically as global but I don't think that's ideal.

Comment: You'll get the same behavior with the solution in my answer, except that you'll be able to automatically update it through npm.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm doing now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since the nice Yanick Rochon's answer does not seem to work in your case, note that you should still be able to load your library the "old fashion" way, using the `[project_root]/client/compatibility/` [special folder](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories).

Any library in that folder will not be loaded in an independent scope by Meteor, but rather loaded "as is" like if it were through a classic `<script>` tag.

Then your `OpenSeadragon` object should become available on global scope.

As a side note, if you need simple image navigation and not the OpenSeadragon advanced features, you might be interested in trying [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/). It is lighter-weight but very stable and well maintained.

Comment: Yeah, for now, I have placed the `openseadragon.js` file inside `client/lib` folder so it loads automatically as global script but I don't think that's ideal. Also, I guess Leaflet is for maps. I need to render zoomable images. Do you know any good library for that? Is it possible to render images using render?

Comment: With Leaflet you can also use simple images. See the [tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html) and [`L.imageOverlay()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#imageoverlay)